# Jain and Buddhist destroying Hindu Temples and Mandirs

Tags: history, temple

We all know of persecution of Muslim dynasties towards Hindus, but many Jains and Buddhist claim, and sometimes with evidence that Hindu kings destroyed Jain and Buddhist temples, but couldn't the inverse be very well true. So, what Hindu mandirs were destroyed by Jains and Buddhist. Please give links to primary sources with good translations as well as if possible photo evidence.

Comment: It’s an erroneous Indological narrative (spread by historians such as Thapar, etc.) that Hindus destroyed any Bauddha or Jaina temples. Sita Ram Goel does show the falsity of many of these narratives.

Comment: @Bingming yeah I agree that widespread persecution is incorrect although I have heard in certain cases that religious places were either destroyed (during warfare) or converted by the community when religious landscape changed, but I am wondering if any Buddhist/Jains did the same, if you don't please refer to primary sources?

Comment: I know Ankorwatt was converted Vishnu temple.

Comment: Converted by Buddhist.

Comment: Angkor Wat was kinda abandoned with time, so the Buddhists just refurbished and renovated it and started using it as a Buddhist temple. So, I wouldn't call it as destruction really. Actually, I am unaware of any such instance of Hindu, Buddhist or Jaina indulging in desecration/destruction of temples of others due to some hate/conflict in India , because the trio has basic decency in this aspect, unlike mlecchas.  Regarding so-called Hindu destroying those of others, you may check https://youtu.be/EAoircvT484?si=wMwvRA5OGiBzKciJ

Comment: @Bingming okay buddy will look into.